# createdon field date-time format

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm-2011, fetchxml

Compiling the following coe always get the same frustrating mistake. I'm trying to compare a "createdon" field to a the present date. I've tried several date format but stil not working...

Error detail : "The date-time format for 23/05/2012 14:01:55 is invalid"

Code snippet:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
                String.Format("{0:dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss}", d);

                FetchExpression fetch = new FetchExpression(@"
                    <fetch distinct='false' mapping='logical'>
                      <entity name='" + context.PrimaryEntityName + "'><filter type='and'><condition attribute='createdon' value='" + d + "' operator='ne'></condition></filter><link-entity name='new_contrats' alias='nombreligne' from='new_contratsid' to='new_contratsid'><filter type='and'><condition attribute='new_contratsid' value='" + contrats.Id + "' operator='eq'></condition></filter></link-entity></entity></fetch>");
```

Any help would be great !

Comment: I think the value is stored in `UTC` and maybe you would need to convert your `DateTime` to by using `.ToUniversal()` or **`.UtcNow()`** OR you should try the sortable datetime pattern `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss`

Comment: +1 for yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss... that is what I use.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers, I had already tried .ToUniversal() and .UtcNow(), just tried out the sortable datetime pattern but still no results !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My [blog posting here](http://thecrmgrid.wordpress.com/2010/05/19/dates-in-fetchxml-queries/) might help. Basically, UTC format but originating user's local offset may effect the underlying value in the database.

Comment: Hi Greg, thanks for your answer. My problem is that I can't change of operator and I still can't find the right format !!

Comment: So if you use UTC format, you still get the error `The date-time format for <some-date> is invalid` ?

Comment: Yes, but I've noticed though that there is a difference of two hours between the time indicated in the error message and the actual time...

Comment: Well the time difference will be because of the offset between UTC and your local time. I presume you are in France and therefore current offset at that location accounts for the 2 hours.

Comment: And I don't understand how you are getting the format error. Can you paste (into your original question) an update with your full FetchXml as generated by your code, before execution?

Comment: Oh God finally got it to work...Like this:

    "DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
    var now = String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss}",d);"

And then using now in the fetchXml...Stupid me...

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier to work in either Linq to CRM or Query Expressions rather than Fetch XML.  You don't have to worry about the formatting since you're working with objects.

Comment: Hi Daryl! I don't really feel comfortable with Linq to CRM or Query expressions. Is msdn a good way get started? Or could you advise me a good website or book? Thanks !

Comment: The SDK has tons of examples.  If you don't already know linq, then I'd focus on the query expressions.  The linq statements get translated to QEs anyway and the CRM implementation of the linq provider has a few gotchas in it.

Comment: Thanks Daryl ! I'll start with query expressions then !