# MS CRM 2011 effectiveintervalend is not correct in DB

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

I am not sure why, but calendar rules, in which you store your business closures differ in UI and in DB. For example if you create business closure with the parameters start = 01.01.2014 and End = 02.01.2014 and days = 2, then in CRM DB (table [CalendarRuleBase]) you`ll get

```
 effectiveintervalstart = 01.01.2014, effectiveintervalend = 03.01.2014.
```

You`ll get the same result when retreiving data using SDK:

```
 Entity org = service.Retrieve("organization", context.OrganizationId, new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query.ColumnSet("businessclosurecalendarid"));

        QueryExpression q = new QueryExpression("calendar");
        q.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true);
        q.Criteria = new FilterExpression();
        q.Criteria.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression("calendarid", ConditionOperator.Equal, org["businessclosurecalendarid"].ToString()));            
        Entity businessClosureCalendar = service.RetrieveMultiple(q).Entities[0];
        if (businessClosureCalendar != null)
        {
            return businessClosureCalendar.GetAttributeValue<EntityCollection>("calendarrules").Entities.ToList();
        }
```

Do you have any idea why this happen? Is effectiveintervalend always one day greater from UI enddate value ?

Comment: Check out this answer as well for links to other similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23042150/227436

Answer (score 1):

Dates in Dynamics CRM database are stored in UTC format, CRM UI automatically convert them to local time so the user will see the correct time.

When you retrieve datetime fields using the SDK, the values are not automatically converted, so you need to use `ToLocalTime()` to get the value depending the timezone of the user making the sdk call.